# Facing problem while creating a Google Portfolio tracking spreadsheet

Tags: stocks, portfolio, spreadsheet, google

I am trying to create a Google Spreadsheet to monitor my Indian stocks and Mutual fund investments. I am facing the following issues and hope someone can help me.

1. When I try to track the 'pe ratio' of indices and mutual funds, I am getting error “Function GOOGLEFINANCE parameter 2 value is invalid for the symbol specified”. However when I try to track the pe ratio of stocks, I can do so. Does it mean that one cannot track the pe ratios of Indian indices and mutual funds? I am using the same formula in all three cases.
2. When I try to track the 'beta' value of indices, mutual funds and stocks, I am getting the same error as above for all three cases. What could be wrong? I am using the formula  =GOOGLEFINANCE(B4, "beta") . When I check the formula, by default, a space is getting inserted between the comma and “beta”.  Why is that happening pls?

You can view the error in this snapshot:

[image: error snapshot]

If you need to inspect the spreadsheet, the [link of the editable spreadsheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WUydSV0yh2D7vbgbhdnvDcKrI-J8ZR0Rd_2Z8emescw/edit?usp=sharing).

I hope you will help me out. I am looking forward to your kind assistance.

Thanks and regards,

Arvind Gupta.

Answer (score 1):

- the space is irrelevant
- as per [the docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB),

> - Some attributes may not yield results for all symbols.
> - `GOOGLEFINANCE` is only available in English and does not support most international exchanges.

Also note the example sheet on that page, showing "common attributes for mutual funds"; note that PE and beta aren't on it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In that case, what is the solution pls? I need to track the beta & PE ratio of various Indian stock market indices and risk metrics of a few mutual funds. I have heard one can integrate various free APIs for the purpose. If it is true, can anyone kindly point me to a relevant API pls. This is the first time I will be tracking various metrics of the stock market. Hence asking. Thanks again, Arvind.